# SSO Application Storing a Custom Secret in the User Profile

Tags: security, encryption, sso

I have an application that employs "zero knowledge" data security, where even with full backend access to our application, customer data cannot be read without knowing their individual passwords. I use what I believe to be a fairly standard method for this: password, after hashing, protects a data key; password change = re-encrypting data key with new password hash. So far so good.

Now we have customers asking for SSO, specifically through AAD and/or Okta. I'm more familiar with AAD at this point, so I'm going to focus on that platform (but answers which address other platforms would be welcome too!).

The obvious problem is that we won't have access to the user password, and thus can't use it to protect the data key. (And even if we did get the password on login, we wouldn't know when it was changed). So how do we make this work without compromising "zero knowledge" security?

My first thought is that for each user added to the application a secret will need to be created in the SSO user profile, and then sent back each time as one of the identity claims or just be retrieved some other way after login. For AAD I believe this can only be done with an [extension attribute](https://learningbydoing.cloud/blog/getting-started-with-azuread-extension-attributes/). There are a few drawbacks to this though, at least with AAD:

1. An AAD admin would be required to add each user to the application (even if they were already in AAD), since only the User Administrator role can apparently set extension property values; unless I'm doing something wrong, standard users cannot set extension attribute values on their own profiles. So this precludes the possibility of the customer's users accessing the application without admin intervention for each user.
2. Customers might not want to give my application the Graph API permission "User.ReadWrite.All" (which, even if under the admin's identity, is needed to write extension properties to the AAD user profiles when they're added to the application). If not, then admins will have to do something like run a Powershell script every time they want to add a user in their Directory to our application; they could not be added purely in-app (even by the admin).
3. Customers might not want to be adding extension properties to their directories at all. This one seems like a deal breaker.

Another option I've considered that at least avoids (1) and (2) is having one secret for the customer, so that they only have to set up the application once and all users could then access it without admin intervention. Even assuming it were possible to get this information returned with each login, the problem is obvious - if that "secret" were compromised it would compromise the whole organization, not just one user.

Finally I've considered just requiring users, as part of the signup process, to pick a PIN that they have to enter every time they log in, even when using SSO. This rather defeats the purpose of SSO, is not going to be popular, and unless the required PIN is long, really doesn't add that much security.

Can anyone suggest any other, better approaches to this, or let me know if I've missed something or am mistaken about anything above?

Update - I'm thinking of exploring using an Azure KeyVault with RBAC. Each user gets their own secret that only they and admins can access. After sign-in the user's AAD access token (the one I can use to call the Graph API, etc.) would be provided to the backend temporarily to access the Key Vault, which would be firewalled with an IP whitelist. Any feedback on this idea would be appreciated!

Comment: This is surely interesting, but I guess this is more a question for AAD experts (and Okta experts) than for software engineers in general. I guess Microsoft offers an AAD forum for questions like this one?

Comment: @DocBrown thanks. I struggled a little with whether this was the best forum. I knew SO wasn't... I tried to be more general than JUST AAD but I'm happy to edit out the AAD-specific parts if it would help.

Comment: @DocBrown I gave the Microsoft forums a shot but the quality of answers on there is pretty abysmal these days so I'm not holding my breath. But again happy to edit this to be more general to make it more appropriate if need be.

Comment: For me. it looks like you need to find out if there is a standard attribute or mechanism in AAD which solves what you are looking for, nothing which you will easily find out when you make the question more general. I am in no way an AAD expert, but by googling, I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes, which mentiones "alternativeSecurityIds". But I don't know exactly what AAD B2C is, if this is different from AAD or if you have the possibility to make use of it.

Comment: How sensitive is the data you are storing? Is it like medical records, or more like a list of liked websites? In other words, how critical is is that you maintain the zero-knowledge per-user encryption?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau curious where you're going with this, but let's just say I have zero knowledge (:D) of what data users might be storing. Seriously, it could be sensitive, and while this is by no means the only security mechanism, it is a selling point I would prefer not to have to compromise just for SSO.

Comment: @DocBrown yeah most of the AAD documentation is awful. I have been searching far and wide for something built into AAD that can handle this. For on-prem AD there is the Windows Data Protection API which would be the obvious soltuion. There doesn't appear to be an equivalent mechanism in AAD. And again AAD isn't the only IDP we are being asked to support, so I suspect all of them are going to have one issue or another. I'm starting to think PIN is going to be the only viable way to go here.

Comment: @PeterMoore, I was trying to get a feeling for how important it is that, in case of a breach, only a single user's data gets exposed.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau FYI many of our customers who are self-hosting are frequent targets of cyber criminals. They're ultimately responsible for thier own security, but it is nice to be able to say, even if the backend were compromised, decrypting the data, user by user, would still be very difficult and resource consuming and not practical for most attackers.